# Javascript Behaviour

Tags: javascript, closures

Just started javascript couple a days ago.
Both those function outputs the same.
So, what's the difference between them?

First Method:

```
function fakeAjax(url,cb) {
    setTimeout(function fakeLoadingDelay(){
        cb([
            "A Song of Ice and Fire",
            "The Great Gatsby",
            "Crime & Punishment",
            "Great Expectations",
            "You Don't Know JS"
        ]);
    },500);
}
```

Second Method:

```
function fakeAjax(url,cb) {
    setTimeout(cb([
            "A Song of Ice and Fire",
            "The Great Gatsby",
            "Crime & Punishment",
            "Great Expectations",
            "You Don't Know JS"
        ])
    ,500);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There is no difference. the first one has just wraped cb() inside of another function.

Comment: "what's the difference between them?" — About 500ms

Comment: @Invizi — "just"? That's a hugely significant difference.

Comment: @Quentin they both have the same delay, and fakeLoadingDelay() just calls cb() so no real difference.

Comment: @Invizi — No. Read the duplicate.